# Research on SLA for "Reading Only"

Tags: reference-request, second-lang-acquisition

Is there research in SLA by graduate students and others who "acquire" a rudimentary understanding of a language primarily for the purpose of reading original academic research and sources in that language?

I am curious about research in language acquisition for academic-professional purposes, when the goal is not oral or written fluency but solely reading. Any starting point or general reference is appreciated!

Comment: A common term for this area of research is *English as an Academic Lingua Franca*.

Comment: You can talk to my Polish professor about this. :) interesting question. +1